# Transpose a file and fill missing fields

Tags: awk

I have tried several awk and sed commands and GNU datamash to change the format and code the missing fields as "??" of this data file with no success. I have a file with a format that looks like the following:

```
ind_1      SNP_1    AA
ind_1      SNP_2    AB
ind_1      SNP_3    AA
ind_2      SNP_1    AA
ind_2      SNP_2    AA
ind_3      SNP_1    AB
ind_3      SNP_2    AA
ind_3      SNP_3    AB
ind_3      SNP_4    AA
```

desired format:

```
            SNP_1      SNP_2    SNP_3      SNP_4
  ind_1      AA       AB       AA         ??
  ind_2      AA       AA       ??         ??
  ind_3      AB       AA       AB         AA
```

i first tried using GNU datamash

```
      datamash --no-strict transpose < input1.txt
```

then i tried this awk:

```
 awk '
      !b[$1 FS $2]++{
    a[++i]=$1 FS $2
    }
    {
   c[$1 FS $2]=c[$1 FS $2]?c[$1 FS $2] FS $4:$4
        }
   END{
for(k=1;k<=i;k++){
  print a[k],c[a[k]]
 }}
'   Input1_txt
```

Comment: You need to show us the code you have written in an attempt to solve this problem for yourself.

Comment: What do Python and Perl have to do with this? And what problem are you having?

Comment: wondering if Python or Perl can solve this problem

Comment: Note that this is not a transpose but a simple pivot table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`awk` to the rescue!

with true multidimensional arrays it would be easier, but this works for most `awk`s

```
awk -v OFS='\t' '{vals[$1]; cols[$2]; a[$1,$2]=$3} 
             END {for(j in cols) printf "%s", OFS j; 
                  print "";
                  for(i in vals) 
                    {printf "%s", i; 
                     for(j in cols) printf "%s", OFS (((i,j) in a)?a[i,j]:"??"); 
                     print ""}}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. for some reason, some fields in some lines remain empty and not filled with "??"

Comment: did you try with the sample input you provided?  make sure you don't have spurious carriage returns in your file if copied from Windows.